# Haskell: Problem with making my own data-type be part of the Eq-typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

i have a data-type, which is declared as:

```
data Card = Card Suit Value deriving (Show, Eq)
```

with:

```
data Suit = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Ord) 

data Value = Spade | Diamond | Club | Heart deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

i made the type Card be part of the typeclass Eq like this:

```
instance Eq Card where
(Card s1 v1) == (Card s2 v2) = (s1 == s2) && (v1 == v2)
```

even though my solution is the exact same as we got it from my uni-class, i always get the following error from ghci:

```
<interactive>:9:1: error:
    Couldn't match type ‘Card’ with ‘Suit’
    Expected type: Suit -> Suit -> Bool
      Actual type: Card -> Card -> Bool

<interactive>:9:49: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Suit’ with actual type ‘Value’
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘v1’
      In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(v1 == v2)’
      In the expression: (s1 == s2) && (v1 == v2)

<interactive>:9:55: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Suit’ with actual type ‘Value’
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘v2’
      In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(v1 == v2)’
      In the expression: (s1 == s2) && (v1 == v2)
```

Comment: Your `Card` is already an instance of `Eq` through `deriving (Show, Eq)`, hence you can not do this a second time.

Comment: I had it like this first, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: But nevertheless I can not replicate this behavior. Did you define an `Eq` typeclass yourself (so `class Eq`)? In that case, the `(==)` is of course no longer the one defined in the original `Eq` typeclass.

Comment: I tried it with define it myself like this: class  Eq a  where
   (==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
   x /= y     =  not (x == y)
   x == y     =  not (x /= y)

Comment: please don't. Right now there are two `Eq` typeclasses, the original one, that probalbly also has `Suit` and `Value` as members and the new one. This class is already defined and imported through the `Prelude`.

Comment: started my terminal new and it's working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What was the solution? I know that restarting the terminal seems to have fixed it for you, but was that the actual fix or did your code change too?

Answer (score 2):

This snippet:

```
instance Eq Card where
(Card s1 v1) == (Card s2 v2) = (s1 == s2) && (v1 == v2)
```

is *not* a valid instance declaration. Because you didn't indent the definition, it does not syntactically belong to the `instance`, i.e. what the compiler sees is just an *empty* instance declaration (which is language-legal, albeit not actually ok for `Eq`; it means you're leaving all the methods at their default), plus an additional standalone definition of an operator called `==`. This operator will have nothing to do with the `Eq` class, i.e. `Prelude.==` and `YourModule.==` will be completely unrelated operators. Normally, this would lead to `Ambiguous occurrence ‘==’` errors, but if you wrote this in GHCi then your version will *shadow* the prelude, i.e. any subsequent use of `==` will refer to your version.

Now, for that operator, the compiler infers from the LHS that it must have type

```
(==) :: Card -> Card -> ...
```

It is *not* polymorphic in the argument type, like `Prelude.==` is.

But then, in the definition body, you call that same operator with `s1` and `s2` as arguments, which is a contradiction and leads to the error message you posted.

What you actually meant to write was

```
instance Eq Card where
  (Card s1 v1) == (Card s2 v2) = (s1 == s2) && (v1 == v2)
```

or

```
instance Eq Card where (Card s1 v1) == (Card s2 v2) = (s1 == s2) && (v1 == v2)
```

Incidentally, the parens are completely unnecessary; I'd recommend this version:

```
instance Eq Card where
  Card s₀ v₀ == Card s₁ v₁ = s₀==s₁ && v₀==v₁
```